# nav2 MPPI plugin controller crashes on startup

Tags: navigation, ros2, ros-humble, nav2

I am currently working with pure pursuit controller and would like to test the MPPI.
Thus I installed the latest binaries *ros-humble-nav2-mppi-controller* which i got in version 1.1.9-1Jammy

So far so good. Then I create the attached configuration and start it. This is where it crashes.

Unfortunately there is no additional output.
**Do I need additional settings or any additional Package for this to work?**

This is the crash output:

```
[bt_navigator-5]        Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[bt_navigator-5]        See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1692711166.503247079] [bt_navigator]: Creating
[planner_server-2] [INFO] [1692711166.515321438] [planner_server]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1692711166.592131125] [lifecycle_manager_pathplanner]: Creating
[behavior_server-3] [INFO] [1692711166.596591543] [behavior_server]: 
[behavior_server-3]     behavior_server lifecycle node launched. 
[behavior_server-3]     Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[behavior_server-3]     See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1692711166.614862942] [lifecycle_manager_pathplanner]: Creating and initializing lifecycle service clients
[planner_server-2] [INFO] [1692711166.641497525] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: 
[planner_server-2]      global_costmap lifecycle node launched. 
[planner_server-2]      Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[planner_server-2]      See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[planner_server-2] [INFO] [1692711166.643438908] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.718496513] [controller_server]: 
[controller_server-1]   controller_server lifecycle node launched. 
[controller_server-1]   Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[controller_server-1]   See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.787895270] [controller_server]: Creating controller server
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.853868449] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: 
[controller_server-1]   local_costmap lifecycle node launched. 
[controller_server-1]   Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[controller_server-1]   See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.855866668] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1692711166.898315701] [lifecycle_manager_pathplanner]: Starting managed nodes bringup...
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1692711166.899380126] [lifecycle_manager_pathplanner]: Configuring controller_server
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.900943575] [controller_server]: Configuring controller interface
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.901594522] [controller_server]: getting goal checker plugins..
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.902379392] [controller_server]: Controller frequency set to 10.0000Hz
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.902612070] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Configuring
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.921993979] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.932225626] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (/map) with transient local durability
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.936113267] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.936366029] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.943776293] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: 
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.944142769] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "obstacle_layer"
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.944311860] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.952675252] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.968426825] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 1000 X 1000 at 0.200000 m/pix
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.981669696] [controller_server]: Created progress_checker : progress_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.986611011] [controller_server]: Created goal checker : goal_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.990603990] [controller_server]: Controller Server has goal_checker  goal checkers available.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1692711166.993440999] [controller_server]: Created controller : FollowPath of type nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController
[ERROR] [controller_server-1]: process has died [pid 5460, exit code -4, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/nav2_controller/controller_server --ros-args -r __node:=controller_server --params-file /opt/greenhive/spritzengel/install/nav2/share/nav2/config/nav2/v3/controller_mppi.yaml -r /cmd_vel:=/hardware/motordriver/cmd_
```

This is the config

```
controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 20.0

    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"] # progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker" For Humble and older
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 30.0
      
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.35
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.78

    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.05
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.5
      vy_std: 0.0
      wz_std: 0.4
      vx_max: 1.0
      vx_min: -0.5
      vy_max: 0.0
      wz_max: 1.9
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 3
      transform_tolerance: 0.3
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "DiffDrive"
      visualize: false
      reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      inversion_yaw_tolerance: 0.7
      AckermannConstrains:
        min_turning_r: 0.2
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 4.0
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.5
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: false
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.1
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
        inflation_radius: 0.55 # (only in Humble)
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 14.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
        trajectory_point_step: 3
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        offset_from_furthest: 20
        use_path_orientations: false
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 5
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
        offset_from_furthest: 4
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
        mode: 0
      # TwirlingCritic:
      #   enabled: true
      #   twirling_cost_power: 1
      #   twirling_cost_weight: 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a ticket we're discussing this issue on GitHub https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3767 - please follow up there.

I'm seeing this report just now from the sync on Friday so this is a new issue that I'm not yet sure what the cause of it is but its being discussed and I'd be happy to have more eyes on it so I can find the issue and get a solution out in the next binary sync